# display 2 <p>'s side by side

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I want to display 2 paragraphs side by side.

```
<p class = "firstClass">This is first line.</p>
<p class = "secondClass">This is second line.</p>
```

Output:

```
This is first line.
This is second line.
```

Desired output:

```
This is first line.This is second line.
```

To achieve desired output, what should I be writing in css file for classes 'firstClass', 'secondClass'?

Answer: I tried "display:inline" for both of classes and then it didn work

Comment: `Note: I tried "display:inline" for both of classes but didn't work` That cannot be true as you see by the answers below. Do you have CSS rules that might be causing an issue that you didn't post?

Comment: Try: `.firstClass, .secondClass {display: inline!important;}`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d91ppydm/ if it didn't work. try @JoostS answer. if still doesn't work add  parent element or class before .firstClass and .secondClass. if still no luck, make sure this css loads at the end after all other css.

Comment: It worked after adding it to both classes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.firstClass, .secondClass {display: inline;}
```

If other CSS is overriding this display setting, increase selector specificity by using:

```
#parent_id .firstClass, #parent_id .secondClass {display: inline;}
```

If that does not help, you can use this AWFUL trick (as a last resort):

```
.firstClass, .secondClass {display: inline!important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Paragraphs are block level elements by default. Change that to inline or inline-block:

`.firstClass, .secondClass { display:inline }`

```css
.firstClass, .secondClass { display:inline }
```

```html
<p class = "firstClass">This is first line.</p>
<p class = "secondClass">This is second line.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `display: inline-block` see example https://jsfiddle.net/jftf8a39/1/

you can use `display: inline` see example https://jsfiddle.net/jftf8a39/5/

you can use `display: flex` on the parent see example https://jsfiddle.net/jftf8a39/3/

You can use `float: left` see example https://jsfiddle.net/jftf8a39/4/